# Why does `list.extend()` interleave `None`s in the resulting list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following example, which is based on a bug I experienced in the past:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.extend(map(lambda n: l.append(10 * n), [4, 5, 6]))
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 40, None, 50, None, 60, None]
```

Why are these `None`s interleaved in the resulting list? By executing `map(lambda n: l.append(10 * n), [4, 5, 6])`, I would expect `l = [1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60]`, and then finally updated to `l = [1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60, None, None None]` by `list.extend()`, since the `map()` operation returns `[None, None, None]`.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Yes, but why are these None's in-between the numbers?

Comment: `map`'s return value is an iterable object whose contents are evaluated lazily. So while `extend` is iterating through it, the `append` inside it is being executed at each step.

Comment: Can you elaborate to a Python novice? If it's evaluated lazily, then why are the None's interleaved? Don't you mean it's evaluated eagerly? So, what you are saying is that `map` returns immediately, returning an interable, that `extend` starts to operate on immediately, so that the order of None's and numbers is actually a race condition?

Comment: Because, `.append` get's evaluated for each element, and **then** `extend` adds the element that comes from the `map` iterator, which will always be `None`. You shouldn't use `map` for side-effects, by the way.

Comment: perhaps it helps if you think of extend as implemented simply as `for x in data_to_be_extended: self.append(x)`

Comment: Note that the ``map`` operation doesn't return ``[None, None, None]``. It returns a lazy iterable that will *eventually* provide ``None``, ``None``, and ``None``.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are interleaving ``extend`` and ``append`` in the first place? There is practically no case where you need to do this in real code. Is this just for curiosity, after encounter the behaviour by accident?

Answer (score 3):

`map(function, sequence)` returns an object that can be iterated. When you iterate it, for each iteration the function is called on the next member of the sequence, until the sequence is finished.

When you pass such an object to `extend`, it is iterated, and at each step the value returned is appended to your original list `l`.

So the iteration goes like:

- get the next value from the map
- the map calls the function on the next value from the sequence

  - as a side effect, this appends a value to your list `l`
- the value None (the return value of `append`) is returned from your function, and added to the list `l`

Therefore the Nones and the explicitly appended values are interleaved in the list.

Comment: I would also specify that `.append` is the function that returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to khelwood's excellent answer on why that happend, here is one solution to get the list that you want (`[1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60]`). I am using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extend the list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.extend([n*10 for n in [4,5,6]])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60]
```

Or by using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.extend(n*10 for n in [4,5,6])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to understand **what** `map()` does, and **how** it do that.

`map()` is a very common function in python. It takes a **selector**, and an **iterable**.

What's an iterable?

In python, iterable is everything you can `for` through it. `list` is obviously an iterable, but `str` too. And there are many, many other iterables, and you can create them yourself (creating iterables handy is an uncommon and (relatively) hard operation in python, however you always create them with `yield`, generator comprehension, and many more).

It's important to understand that **iterable** is different from **sequence**. A **sequence** is something you can access its item using square-brackets notation, slice it etc.. An **iterable** is a more basic form which you can only iterate over it. Most of the sequences are iterable, although that's not necessary.

A **selector** is a function (or to be more accurate, a **callable** - something you can use the `()` operator on it, possibly with parameters). The selector is a function with special signature: it takes one argument - an item in the iterable, and returns another form of that item.

What `map()` does is transforming its iterable parameter into another iterable, when the new iterable's item are the ones of the original one - when taken into the selector and the result was inserted into the result.

If I would implementing `map()` myself, it would be less or more like (this is not the actual implementation of `map()` in python 3 but rather in python 2, because the one in python 2 returns a `list`, while the python 3's version returns an iterable. This is less memory-consuming, but also harder to implement so I won't focus on that).

```py
def map(selector, iterable):
    result = []
    for item in iterable:
        to_insert = selector(item)
        result.append(to_insert)
    return result
```

Now let's analyze you code.

The `lambda` syntax creates an anonymous function with one expression. `f = lambda a, b, c: x` is equal to

```py
def f(a, b, c):
    return x
```

Let's check what happens inside `map()`.

First of all, we know our iterable is `[4, 5, 6]` and our selector is:

```py
def <anonymous>(n):
    return l.append(n * 10)
```

To simplify your code, I'll assume for now it was written like:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = list(map(lambda n: l.append(n * 10), [4, 5, 6]))
l1.extend(l2)
```

(You can also run your code with python 2 instead). We'll see the difference at a moment.

We see that our function returns the return value of `list.append()`. So, we ask ourselves, what does `list.append()` return? It doesn't have a return value, after all, not so?

Not exactly. In python, **there is no such thing "no return value"**. If there is not an explicit `return` statement, the return value is `None`.

So, we know `list.append()` returns `None`. Let's continue:

`map()` takes the first element, 4. It passes it to its selector - the lambda. The lambda takes it, multiplies it by 10 (40), then append the result to `l` and returns `None`. Currently, `l` consists of `[1, 2, 3, 40]` and `map()`'s result consists of `[None]`.

Continue with this train of thought, and you'll find that at the end `l` is `[1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60]` while `map()`'s result is `[None, None, None]`. We append `map()`'s result to `l`, so at end `l` is `[1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60, None, None, None]`.

But why in your example the `None`s are in the middle? To understand that, we need to go deeper into our understanding of the difference between what `map()` returns - also called, more general, a **generator** - and a `list`.

Let's start with a simple example. To start, I'll precede and say that the `yield` keyword returns multiple values, like a list - i.e. each `yield` is a new value in the "list" (like) in the function's result. For instance,

```py
def func():
    yield 1
    yield 2
```

The result of the call to `func()` is an iterator that returns 1 and then 2.

What the next code will print, in your opinion?

```py
def func():
    yield 1
    print('here!')
    yield 2
func()
```

The answer is: nothing! While the slightly different following code:

```py
def func():
    yield 1
    print('here!')
    yield 2
for _ in func(): pass
```

Or even the following code (notice - we do nothing with the returned `list`):

```py
def func():
    yield 1
    print('here!')
    yield 2
list(func())
```

Both will print `here!`, as expected. Why?

Because, and this is the biggest advantage of generators: they're in practice never run.

What??!!!!!!!!

OK, I wrong. They're never run - until you iterate over them. In programming, this is called [**lazy evaluation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

This term means: when you meet a code, you actually don't need to run it - you need that only when you need the results.

The code after the first `yield` in the first example never run. When the python engine met the first `yield` - it stops, and wait for a "hint" to continue. Until the current item is not requested, there'is not reason to continue to the next. The `for` loop, however, consumed the first item - then the next part, until the second `yield` in the function was executed. The `list` constructor also iterates over its parameter and appends each item to the newly created list. Both triggered the call to `print()`.

This also leads to the opposite behavior: what will the following print?

```py
def func():
    yield 1
    print('here!')
    yield 2
generator = func()
l1 = list(generator)
l2 = list(generator)
print(l1, l2)
```

The answer is: `[1, 2] []`. The second call to `list` returned an empty list - because the iterator was already consumed and reached its end (however, if you'll call `func()` again, a new generator will be created. There can also be some generators from the same function in the same time - but a generator is one-time iterable).

Now let's analyze your output.

First, `map()` taked the first item - 4, in our case - and passed it to the lambda. The lambda added 40 to `l` and returned `None`.

Now, `map()` is stopping - it won't continue until the `None` (the argument of the `yield`) is consumed.

Let's continue with the flow of the code:

`list.extend()` is called. It's a function that takes an iterable, and appends it to the end of the list. `extend()` consumed the first item returned from `map()` - `None` - and appended it to the list. Now it requested the next.

Currently the list is: `1`, `2`, `3`, `40` (added by the lambda) and `None` (added by `extend()`).

Continue with the same logic, and you'll find an alternate stream of numbers and `None`s. That's you result.